# exponent simplification as common factor

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]Can anyone tell me how the `?` in image was derived? Please pardon me for using an image as I am not experienced with using MathJax.

Comment: Hint: $\sum_{m=1}^{k+1} f(m) = f(k+1) + \sum_{m=1}^k f(m)$ for any function $f$.  This is a consequence of the meaning of sigma notation (for some people, even the definition of sigma notation).

Comment: ty for reply; although makes sense but any references would help

Comment: The "formal definition" section in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation provides one an example of this. In the second equation display, take their index "$i$" to be your index "$m$", their starting point "$a$" to be $1$, and their ending point "$b$" to be your $k+1$, etc.

Comment: How to format math on this website: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: ty but it seems image format was easy rather than difficult code like math format; iam a medico but thanks anyway ... also kindly tell how to close the question as there are many questions based on "exponent simplification" and @leslie comment was enough to provide insight about the problem query.

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion is, how $$\sum_{m=1}^{k+1} (-1)^{k+1-m}m^2=(k+1)^2 + \sum_{m=1}^{k}(-1)^{k+1-m}m^2?$$
@leslie townes's answer is enough for your confusion. But in case you still didn't understand, then see following example.
$1+2+...+9+10= \sum_{i=1}^{10}i= (\sum_{i=1}^{9} i)+10$
In above example adding first ten natural numbers is same as adding first nine natural numbers and then adding $10$ to the final answer.
In general $\sum_{m=1}^{k} f(m)= (\sum_{m=1}^{k-1} f(m)) + f(k).$

Now in your problem we have $f(m)=(-1)^{k+1-m} m^2$. We see
$\sum_{m=1}^{k+1}(-1)^{k+1-m}= (\sum_{m=1}^{k} (-1)^{k+1-m}m^2)+(-1)^{k+1-(k+1)}(k+1)^2=(k+1)^2+ \sum_{m=1}^{k}(-1)^{m+1-k}m^2$.

**Edit:** I only had explained the answer of leslie townes.